# How can I overwrite the exported CSV file using Python in Dynamo for Revit?

Tags: python, revit-api

This Dynamo/Python script is working great. I'm just trying to do the same but overwrite the file with the new export every time I export. I don't need to append or save any older version. Just the newest version. How can I modify the Python script to achieve this? [Pic of Dynamo Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEihu.png)

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

schedule = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
path = IN[1]
name = IN[2]

try:
    exp_opt = ViewScheduleExportOptions()
    schedule.Export(path, name, exp_opt)
    OUT = "Done"

except: OUT = "Failed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any property suggesting overwriting in the ViewScheduleExportOptions class.

So a dirty way of doing this, would be deleting the file if it already exists.

```py
import clr
import os

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

schedule = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
path = IN[1]
name = IN[2]

try:
    try:
        os.remove(path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    exp_opt = ViewScheduleExportOptions()
    schedule.Export(path, name, exp_opt)
    OUT = "Done"

except: OUT = "Failed"
```